# How to move WMS layers independently using OpenLayers 3 (with GeoServer)

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I have two GeoServer WMS layers on OpenLayers 3 map. What I need to do is to make a button that will move one layer, let's say 10m to the East. Other layers should not move. Moved layer should keep 10m offset when zooming and panning.

I looked through OpenLayers documentation and examples, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to make GeoServer to move the layer. You should make your OpenLayers application to use a tailored SLD or SLD_BODY for that layer and SLD should use the vendor parameter "offset". See the "Shadow" example in http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/geometry-transformations.html

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I must admit that I never used external parameters for SLD but I will try. I hope this isn't too CPU intensive for the server.