# How to move and rotate WMS layers independently using OpenLayers (without GeoServer)

Tags: openlayers, javascript, wms, rotate, move

There are maps on OpenLayers 6 and proj4js that manages WMS layers in different projections. Sometimes (e.g. for plan maps) the overlay is not aligned with base layer and a need a function that can move and rotate the WMS layer, so the user can align the layer.

I found this answers:

- [How to move WMS layers independently using OpenLayers 3 (with
  GeoServer)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119451)
- [Moving WMS overlay independently to match base layer in
  OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428240)

But I can't apply in my case because I don't manage the server and the layer is not a vector origin.

How does OpenLayers draw the map in the canvas?

I'd expect there's some point in the code in which I could add a offset and rotate to the layer image that has been retrieved from WMS.

The solution proposed in the second answer solves only half of the problem (displacement), but the rotation problem remains unresolved...

```
const source = new ImageWMS({
  url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
  params: {LAYERS: 'topp:states'},
  ratio: 1,
  serverType: 'geoserver',
  imageLoadFunction: function (image, src) {
    const offsetX = 100000;
    const offsetY = 100000;
    const url = new URL(src);
    const params = url.searchParams;
    const oldParams = params.toString();
    const bbox = params.get('BBOX').split(',').map(Number);
    bbox[0] -= offsetX;
    bbox[1] += offsetY;
    bbox[2] -= offsetX;
    bbox[3] += offsetY;
    params.set('BBOX', bbox.toString());
    const newParams = params.toString();
    image.getImage().src = src.replace(oldParams, newParams);
  },
});
```

Comment: This example might help you in the right direction: https://codesandbox.io/s/reprojection-image-z0uit

Comment: Thank you @TomazicM, this is the right recipe to solve the problem!

Comment: I don't seem to understand how reprojection works, or for global projections, this method requires improvement: https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-image-move-rotate-reprojection-notwork-4028h7 In any case, I am grateful to you for the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For user controlled fine alignment you could translate the layer canvas context before rendering the layer.  The important part of the code would look like

```
wmsLayer.on('prerender', function (event) {
  const resolution =
    event.frameState.pixelRatio * event.frameState.viewState.resolution;
  event.context.save();
  event.context.translate(offsetX / resolution, offsetY / resolution);
});

wmsLayer.on('postrender', function (event) {
  event.context.restore();
});
```

Example https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-image-forked-71k9nh?file=/main.js

If you need to set an anchor for scaling or rotation that could be done by clicking on the map with a modifier key such alt, control or shift, for example:

```
map.on('click', function(event){
  if (platformModifierKeyOnly(event)){
    anchor = event.coordinate;
    wmsLayer.changed();
  }
});
```

Comment: I suppose rotate could also be done this way?

Comment: It seems this does not work correctly when you do offset and then zoom in. Something with the extent goes wrong.

Comment: You could also scale and rotate, but you would also need to set an anchor coordinate for those, which would need the `getRenderPixel` method as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-swipe.html and take care to do multiple changes in the correct order (e.g. translate to anchor point, scale and rotate, translate back) or have a good understanding of transform matrixes.

Comment: If the zoom in you will be unable to offset beyond what the WMS is serving for the viewport.

Comment: Thank you, a working version. Although you need to mess around a bit with the rotation - you can't limit the extent layer and you need to know the original extent of the layer for correct rotation. Perhaps something else needs to be taken into account

Comment: I'm not sure that you need to know the extent.  The image could be rotated around any coordinate inside or outside of the extent.  If inside there would be one point where, without correction, the WMS and the background coincided.  The user would need to enter those coordinates, I think a click event could be used, as added to the answer.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that to rotate around the center of the Layer, you need to know its extent. In addition, apparently, separate requests are needed to get an uncut layer... https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-image-move-rotate-prerender-weqq37

Comment: Yes, if you want to rotate around that point it helps to know it, but there is no guarantee that is where rotation will need to be centered, the correct point might a corner of the image, or anywhere.  Here the anchor is initially set at the extent center, but can be changed with Ctrl-click on the map https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-image-move-rotate-prerender-forked-bx1j21